# ActionBarActivity can not resolve from popstack

Tags: android

When I use the device's back button to return to my first `Activity` (`MainActivity.java` below) from my second (`MainActivity2.java` below), my first `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method is called every time, but if I use the `ActionBar`'s back button then my `onCreate()` method is not called.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package exam.mcq.it.intentdemo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Create method call",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity2.java**

```
package exam.mcq.it.intentdemo;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="exam.mcq.it.intentdemo" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="exam.mcq.it.MainActivity2" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: MainActivity2->onOptionsItemSelected()->do: if (id == R.id.home){finish();}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used a small hack, not sure if this is the right way to do. I called the onBackPressed() method when the arrow is pressed.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_save:
                            save();
                            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            //Pressing on up Arrow was calling onCreate of MainActivity
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
```

Your question is not clear so I am assuming you do not want onCreate() to be called when Arrow in actionBar is pressed.

Comment: ya i dont want to call onCreate() method when Arrow in actionBar is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

Override `onBackPressed ()` function in the activity. That function will be called when the back press button is used.  Also, refer the life cycle of an activity in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: You should never be calling `onCreate()` or other lifecycle methods yourself.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks. I deleted that part

Comment: i dont want to call Oncreate() method when i come back previous activity